# Replace part of a folder and its subfolders names using batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

I have a folder structure on my Computer which are all in the form e.g. "Photos" then subfolders "Summer 2012" "Winter 2012" and they have further subfolders. I want to place the name "David" before each folder name i.e. "David Photos" "David Summer 2012" etc. . Is there a batch file i can write to do this? My last attempt was the following:

```
for /D /R %%G IN ("\\sampledrive\Photos") DO (REN "%%G" "dan%%G")
```

However the command window said the syntax of the command was incorrect

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? You can use `ren C:\files David files` in a `for` loop

Comment: The last program i tried was:
@echo off
for /D /R %%G IN ("\\Sampledrive\Photos") DO ( REN "%%G" "David %%G")
exit
It scrolled trough the command window saying "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

Comment: Put your sample code into your question [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31829193/edit) rather than within a comment...

Answer (score 1):

Using `REN "%%G" "David %%G"` will rename the folder to "David \sampledrive\Photos", so cmd returns the syntax is incorrect. Use `%%~nxG` instead, it indicates the folder, not the path.

```
@echo off 
For /D /r "\sampledrive\Photos" %%G IN (*) DO ( 
    REN "%%G" "David %%~nxG"
)
echo Finished!
pause >nul
```

Answer (score 0):

`for /R` puts a full path starting with a drive letter into the loop variable so prepending it with a text like `"David %%G"` would try to create an invalid file name: `"David c:\folder\file"`.

To rename a fuly specified folder/file as the first argument of `ren` it's sufficient to provide only file/folder name.ext in the second argument: `ren "%%G" "David %%~nxG"`.

However renaming *while* enumerating may expose the already renamed file to enumeration once again and it may continue ~40 times until 260 path length limit is reached and you'll have a file named as `David David David ...........`.

Iterate over a list of the existing folders obtained via `dir`:

```
for /f "delims=" %%G in ('dir /s /ad /b "\sampledrive\Photos"') do ren "%%G" "David %%~nxG"
```